# Anyway to optimise this parallax script for better performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I have a parallax script that I am using to slow the background position of an element relative to the window scroll. It performs GREAT on my macbook pro but on slower computers it shudders more than I feel it needs to.

Here is the code below:

```
    var bgobj = $('.paral');

    $(window).scroll(function () {

        onScroll(bgobj);

    });

function onScroll(bgobj) {

    var $window = $(window);

    var yPos = ($window.scrollTop() / bgobj.data('speed'));
    // Put together our final background position
    var coords = yPos + 'px';

    // Move the background
    bgobj.css({ backgroundPositionY: coords });
```

}

So my question is, what optimisations can be made to the code to improve speed on lower machines?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered throttling?

http://underscorejs.org/#throttle

http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

```
var bgobj = $('.paral');

var onScrollThrottled = _.throttle(onScroll, 100);

$(window).scroll(function () {

    onScrollThrottled(bgobj);

});

function onScroll(bgobj) {

    var $window = $(window);

     var yPos = ($window.scrollTop() / bgobj.data('speed'));
     // Put together our final background position
     var coords = yPos + 'px';

     // Move the background
     bgobj.css({ backgroundPositionY: coords });

     if (isScrolledIntoView($('#more-info'))) {

         animateCircle();

     }
}
```

Of course, instead of throttling/debouncing the entire onScroll function you can apply the optimisation to animateCirle or updating the background css

Comment: This is great, I haven't used throttling before. I will try it and report back.

Comment: Unfortunately if I apply throttling, it ruins the effect and does the opposite of what I am trying to fix. I need to make it as smooth as possible.

Comment: gotcha. Not sure what animateCircle does, but bgobj background position could be heavy too. Have you tried profiling (at least with console.time, console.timeEnd) to see which routine takes the most of the computation time? If it's indeed the background, then try moving bgobj instead of it's background and use css transitions rather than top (watch this: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/ )

Obviously I don't know what your product looks like, so this could be completely off

Comment: I'm removing animateCircle from the original code in the question, as the performance still suffers *without* it. As for your other suggestions I will have a look and report back, thanks.

Comment: I used translate: transform and the performance is even worse. This leads me to think that something else is having an indirect effect.

The website i'm working on in question is http://pingtune.com

Comment: ah, that's better! Not sure why you have to update background position through JS. Seems like CSS' job? I think finding a CSS way to do what you want to do here would be the best "optimisation" in that it would make it A LOT faster

Comment: btw, your site's layout reminded me of this: http://www.seditionart.com/ inspect the large image at the top, you'll see there's no style updates on in when you scroll. Copy?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38437/discussion-between-konstantin-k-and-carbondry)

Answer (score 0):

I see some minor improvements to be done. Nothing big:

```
//cache $window and speed

var $window = $(window);
var bgobj = $('.paral');
var speed = bgobj.data('speed')

$window.scroll(function () {
    onScroll(bgobj);
});

function onScroll(bgobj) {



var yPos = ($window.scrollTop() / speed);
// Put together our final background position
//var coords = yPos + 'px'; // this is not needad as jQuery defaults to pixels if nothing is specified

// Move the background
bgobj.css({ backgroundPositionY: coords });

if (isScrolledIntoView($('#more-info'))) { // depending on what is inside this function, this might slow everything doen

    animateCircle();

}
```